# How to get checked values of input tag which has array-name and send this values to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a html-form:

```
<input name="arrayname[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="arrayname[]" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input name="arrayname[]" type="checkbox" value="3">
<input name="arrayname[]" type="checkbox" value="4">
```

Note the name attribute of input tag is set as `arrayname[]`.
If I click some checkboxes and submit form then I get in $_POST global array:

```
["arrayname"]=>
    array(2) {
    [0]=>
        string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
        string(1) "3"
    }
```

I want to get checked values from input tag using jQuery for sending them to server via ajax. I have invented javascript function:

```
function myGetValue(fieldName)
{
    var value;
    value = $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val();
    return value;
}
```

But this function works with simple names without square brackets like 'simplename'. For example:

```
<input name="simplename" type="text" value="my text">

<input name="arrayname[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="arrayname[]" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input name="arrayname[]" type="checkbox" value="3">
<input name="arrayname[]" type="checkbox" value="4">
```

If I do `alert(myGetValue('simplename'))` then it is ok and I get the value of input field. If I do `alert(myGetValue('arrayname'))` then it is NOT ok and I get 'undefined'.
What function must be in use? I want to get value of input tag with name 'arrayname' and send it to server via ajax. I can't use serialization or json. I want to get the same array like the $_POST even using ajax.
You can see my code in live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aPJ8u/)

I want send checked values only.
My code to send data via ajax:

```
var fieldName = 'simplename';
var fieldValue = myGetValue(fieldName);
var formaData = new FormData();
formaData.append(fieldName, fieldValue);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: formaData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
});
```

Comment: FYI, `.val()` will return only first matched element value. Wouldn't you wish to return an array instead?

Comment: You have syntax error when declare a name in javascript and the programming too. It can not contain brackets

Comment: @hicurin why it can't?

Comment: I have never see it before when I start programming! So Is it ok?

Comment: @hicurin this is valid

Comment: Thanks you Mr A. Wolff! I have just learn something new about javascript.

Comment: @A. Wolff How implement this?

Comment: @YarLinux undeleted my ansewr, check if it fit your needs. But now i guess, you only want to send checked value, not all

Comment: Yes, I want to send checked values only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the values of the checked checkbox elements as below - it will return an array

```
function myGetValue(fieldName) {
    var value = $('input[name="' + fieldName + '"]:checked, input[name="' + fieldName + '"]:not(:checkbox, :radio)').map(function () {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    return value;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BnLTG/)

Comment: Ok. But if I don't know from the begining what will be used: 'arrayname' or 'simplename'? If I do `alert(myGetValue('simplename'))` (without square brackets) then it's not working :( Do you know any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code. But is there way to pass the name of field in the function without square brackets?  From the begining it is not known what kind of data in field. So I think the pure way is `myGetValue('simplename')` and `myGetValue('arrayname')` without brackets after 'arrayname'.

Comment: you can do something but it will be costly in terms of performance

Comment: BTW. How to transform value from 'arrayname' to the array? Array for 'arrayname' needed to pass it to server correctly. For 'simplename' it is ok because it is suitable to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define name as a Javascript Array object. It's a regular string.

Comment: It is legal to use <input name="arrayname[]" type="checkbox" value="1">. The problem is how to use this syntax for javascript. Can you suggest any javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function myGetValue(fieldName)
{
    var value;
    value = $('input[name="'+fieldName+'[]"]').val();
    //or
    //value = $('input[name="'+fieldName+'[]:checked"]').val();
    return value;
}

alert(myGetValue('arrayname'));
```

you field name is `arrayname[]` so u have to give `[]` along with the name and also selector should be `$('input["name="arrayname[]"]')`

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aPJ8u/2/)

**Updated**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function myGetValue(fieldName)
{
    var values =  [];   
    $('input[name="'+fieldName+'[]"]:checked').each(function(i) {
        values[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    return values.join(",");
}

   alert(myGetValue('arrayname'));
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rynhe/aPJ8u/8/)

Comment: I have inspected your code and it doesn't work :(. It returns only "1" always. But I need to choose several checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var checked_boxes = [];
$('input[name^=arrayname]:checked').each(function(){
    checked_boxes[checked_boxes.length] = $(this).val();
});
alert(checked_boxes);
```

Comment: No. This problem is in your code: 1. Must be: $('input[name^='+fieldName+']:checked').each.... 2. myGetValue('arrayname');

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it, so what i'm guessing is that you are looking for following behaviour:

[check your console](http://jsfiddle.net/aPJ8u/4/)

```
function myGetValues(fieldName) {
    return $('input[name=' + fieldName.replace(/(\[)|(\])/g, function (m) {
        return "\\" + m;
    }) + ']').map(function(){return this.value}).get();
}

console.log(myGetValues('arrayname[]'));
```

Comment: I don't know from the begining what is 'arrayname'. It can be a string or array. So it is not possible `myGetValues('arrayname[]')`. Only `myGetValues('arrayname')`.

Comment: And it is not working. It produces `array(1) {
  ["number"]=>
  string(0) ""
}` in $_POST always.

Comment: Try that:  http://jsfiddle.net/RZED3/1/  Regarding your POST issue, i don't know how do you send data... You should send all values, because in your posting code, like already said, you are only getting first element value

Comment: I have tried your code. It gets all values from input tag with name 'fieldName' even I have not checked them. So I have '1,2,3,4' always.

Comment: For your previous message: my code is correct if I use 'simplename' which has not square brackets.

Comment: to get only checked: http://jsfiddle.net/RZED3/2/  btw, fixed error in prvious jsfiddle

Comment: First off, it doesn't work for 'simplename'. Second, I have `array(1) {
  ["arrayname"]=>
  string(3) "1,2"
} ` in $_POST but I need something like `["arrayname"]=>
    array(2) {
    [0]=>
        string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
        string(1) "2"
    }`. I have corrected my first topic where I point my way to send data via ajax.

Comment: @YarLinux ya, `simplename` is not a checkbox, so just modify selector to accept any input which is not an unchecked checkbox, not that hard. But i guess, you have try anything to solve it... That said, why not using $(form).serialize(); ??? http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: I want to send only one field. If FormData object works for 'simplename' so there is way to work for 'arrayname', isn't it?

Comment: ya sure, but simplename is a single element when arrayname are multiple elements... So, you cannot return value of all elements without looping or returning for example an array. If only one checkbox can be checked at a time, don't use checkbox, use grouped radio buttons...

Comment: I try to invent universial function. Anyway, thanks! Our discussion is not vain. Now we have the way to get all checked values from 'arrayname'. http://jsfiddle.net/RZED3/2/. I will try next steps.